How to fix relative import module error in VSCode
I am trying to import a local module in my code using VSCode in my langcahin app but I am getting the following error

here is my file structure

and the service.py file where I am trying to import the module

I am running 'langchain serve' command while I am on the my-app directory.
Also I have created a settings.json file in the .vscode with the following content
{
"python.analysis.extraPaths": [
    "./Artificial Intelligence/LLMs/LANGSERVE/my-app/packages/sql-pgvector"
]

}


"python.analysis.extraPaths"`

This setting is for pylance, which only provides intellisense when editing and will not find related modules at runtime, so moduleNotFound error will occur.
You could add .env file under your workspace and add the following codes:
PYTHONPATH=PATH/TO/sql_pgvector

Then add the following codes to your settings.json:
"python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env"

You could use debug mode(f5) or interactive window to run this python file.
